# Hortonworks sandbox $HIVE_HOME path

Tags: hadoop, hive, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I am back again with a stupid question i think.
I downloaded the Hortonworks sandbox and tried :

```
echo $HIVE_HOME
```

and nothing. Can someone guide me what the path might be ?
In the hive-site.xml i get the below lines:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/apps/hive/warehouse</value>
</property>
```

But this path doesn't exists on the box.
Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for bothering. The path is :

```
hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse/

    [root@sandbox current]# vi /etc/hive/conf.install/hive-site.xml
```

Searched for the warehouse path and got /apps/hive/warehouse

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the .bashrc and setting your $HIVE_HOME environment variable?

Try this

`sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`

Copy and paste the following lines at end of the file

`# Set HIVE_HOME
export HIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-0.13.0-bin"
PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export PATH`

You can look at this page and maybe that will help you further
http://doctuts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hive.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to find Hive warehouse directory:

- Check the hive configuration and search for `warehouse.dir`:

  `cat /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml | less`

  To search, inside less type `/warehouse.dir` (when done, press `q` to exit less).

  `<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/apps/hive/warehouse</value>
  </property>`
- Execute the `SET` Hive QL command. You can run it in Hue (in Amabri switch to Hive view) or in the command line. I will show you how to run it in command line and find the parameter.:

  `[maria_dev@sandbox learn]$ hive -S -e 'SET' 2>/dev/null | grep warehouse.dir
  hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/apps/hive/warehouse`

  Because Hive prints a lot of information to the stderr, I added the `2>/dev/null` output redirect to supress the stderr output from being written to the console.